# alert(new Boolean(false)) vs console.log(new Boolean(false))

Tags: javascript, boolean

I wonder why `alert(new Boolean(false))` prints false  instead of printing object as new Boolean should return object. It works as it should work if I use `console.log(new Boolean(false))`

Comment: `alert` expects a string, so it converts your boolean to string. Nothing strange here, works as expected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`alert()` displays the `.toString()` value of the argument that is passed to it.

The `toString()` value of a `Boolean` object is either `true` or `false`.

Comment: `console.log(Boolean("false"));` it throw true as output why so ?

Comment: @PardeepJain the `Boolean()` function will convert any non-empty string to `true` and empty strings to `false`: `Boolean('false') === true`, `Boolean('hello') === true`, `Boolean('') === false`.

Comment: yeah found same solution already btw thanx :) one more thing `consol.log(Boolean(0))` will also return `false` may be because of Boolean of false =0 whereas true =1.

Answer (score 0):

`alert()` is showing its value in its primitive form, since, Boolean is a primitive datatype. Then it tries to convert it to a String and the output is shown to the user.

That is what `console.log()` is also doing, however it shows in a little more detail, in the form of a Boolean Primitive Value like this: 
`{[[PrimitiveValue]]: false}`

The same will happen with any Primitive value types. Try `new Number(1)`.

Answer (score 0):

when Boolean is used as a constructor, it doesn't return a primitive, Instead it returns an object, and console.log  displays that object. where as alert used the toString defined for the object to display the value.